# BPMN: Do Deadline Timers need their own flow line?

Tags: bpmn

I am capturing my company's formal software release process using BPMN.  We do major releases of our software on a quarterly basis, and there are a number of gates which are X days before release day, e.g. "No further additions to the scope the quarterly release after T-minus 37 days" where T is release day.

Edit: The gateways start with "Register the project for this release", proceed through deadlines for critical documents like "Publish Design Documentation" and "Publish Test Plan" and denote drop dead dates for completing implementation, QA testing and such.  For example, if the QA testing isn't finished 18 days before the release date, the project is pulled from that quarter's release.  I want to capture that in this process documentation.

The correct way to document these (AFAIK) is to use an interrupting timer like so:
[image]

My question is, if in all cases the timer traces to the same location as the base activity, could I omit the redundant flow / trace line?  It seems to me it will clutter up my diagram to have all these activities tracing two lines each to the same next point in the process.

Some additional context: use of BPMN is still unusual at my company, and I very much want to create "correct" diagrams as part of building up a collection of reference diagrams to show other people.  So if the formally correct way is to trace from both the activity and the event, then I want to do that.  I'm hoping that there is an accepted convention that supports a single trace.

edit: Our process is that PMs can add as many projects to the release as they want up until the deadline, after which they'll have to put the projects into a subsequent release.  However, throughout the project there are a bunch of timing gates such as "QA testing complete and test report delivered" that we also have to meet.  This process has six or seven of these.

I was wondering if I could do it like so, sending the timer to an end point so as to illustrate you had to finish the activity before the timer expires or exit the process:

[image]

Another method that draws on the first answer:

[image]

I like this one the most from a clarity stand-point. According to Silver's "The Rules of BPMN" says "All flow nodes other than end events and throwing Link events must have an outgoing sequence flow..." which this representation does, because the timer is guaranteed to fire.

Answer (score 0):

Considering your use case, timer events are probably not a good solution.
Your process implies that projects are registered once (all of them together), whereas your textual description suggests projects can be added multiple times for one release, given they meet the required deadline.

So actually, you have two processes:

1. Register project for release
2. Release software

*Register project for release* is a process frequently executed by a team lead or project manager, I suppose.

*Release software* is a process executed by the release managing team (for example).

The *Register project for release* process contains some decision logic that decides for which release the project is registered. This information is saved in a document/data store to be accessed during the *Release software* process.

Below, you see a sketch of the processes (both in the same diagram):

[image]

Note that the decision logic is hidden in a *Business Rule Task*.
Of course, the decision logic needs to determine if the project can still be added to the current release. This can be done with the help of an *Exclusive Gateway*.
However, you might want to consider the [Decision Model and Notation](http://www.omg.org/spec/DMN/), which complements BPMN to better represent decision logic, for this.

Comment: I understand the intent of your approach, but I'm not certain it will work in my case because I have six or seven of these time dependent gates in my process.  I've added an alternate approach to the main question; does that seem like a "correct" representation?

Comment: You say: " I have six or seven of these time dependent gates in my process". What do these Gateways determine? Whether a project will be added to the release? I'd say that probably either the project mgr or release mgr determines at one point - based on some conditions - whether a project should be added to the release or not. If this assumption is correct, then you can use my 'decision task' approach. I don't get why this decision should be made over and over again.

Comment: In general, if a given project misses a gate in the release process, it's removed from that release.  So if the development isn't finished by a certain point, or the QA testing isn't complete, they have to wait for the next release cycle.

Comment: In your model, "Register releases" is an activity that is cancelled when the deadline arrives. This doesn't make sense. According to your last comment, projects are registered initially and then actively removed by someone (release mgr) if they don't meet a deadline. Then you need a "remove projects" task after each deadline. In this task/sub process, you could go into the details of the decision logic.

Comment: You are correct.  I spoke with the process owner and there is another process to handle projects that miss a deadline.  Some are removed, but often some accommodation is found that keeps them in the release.  My timers now flow to appropriate activities, with outcomes of continuing in the release process or removing the offending project.  Do you think it would be of any interest if I posted my final diagram for anyone viewing this in the future?

Comment: Your issue evolved quite a lot from the initial question, but it might be helpful to document your approach of handling deadlines. Of course, you could also wait and see if your process matures over time (for example if co-workers suggests improvements/simplifications).